# I can't peer my nodes using HASHICORPS vault solution with raft

Tags: nodes, hashicorp-vault, raft, vault

Im trying to set up a 2nodes Vault ( I know that I should use 3 but for now for test I use 2) with raft HA.
For the try I did this morning I used this config file for both node

```
storage "raft" {
  path    = "./vault/data"
  node_id = "node1"
retry_join{
leader_api_addr="http://public ip of the other node:8200"
}
}
listener "tcp"{
address ="0.0.0.0:8200"
tls_disable="true"
}
api_addr = "http://public ip of this node:8200"
cluster_addr = "http://public ip of this node:8201"
ui = true
disable_mlock=true
```

Then did

```
sudo vault server -config=/etc/vault.d/vault.hcl
```

On both nodes.

Then on node 1 :

```
export VAULT_ADDR=http://private ip of this node:8200
Vault operator init
vault unseal ( first one )
vault unseal (second one )
vault unseal (third one)
vault login ( with root token)
```

Then on node 2

```
export VAULT_ADDR=http://private ip of this node:8200
vault operator join "http://public ip of my first node"
```

Unfortunatly it doesn't work I have after 50 seconds this error :

[Error picture after trying to join first node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjp8J.png)
Note that in the logs text I can see that my node is trying to join my first vault but it doesn't work :

[Logs of second node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP4qJ.png)

After those fail I try to unseal my second node
Then if I unseal my second node :

```
vault operator init
vault unseal ( first one with the unseal key gave on node 2)
vault unseal ( second one with the unseal key gave on node 2)
vault unseal ( third one with the unseal key gave on node 2)
vault login (with root token)
vault operator raft join "http://public ip of my first node:8200"
Key       Value
---       -----
Joined    true
```

So now I have an answer after trying vault operator raft join "http://public ip of my first node:8200"

Then if i check on node 1 if my second node joined I have this :

```
vault operator raft list-peers
Node     Address                                     State     Voter
----     -------                -----     -----
node1    public ip of this node:8201    leader    true
```

So it's prety problematic because either I don't have any answer when trying to join my vault or if i Unseal the second node I have a fake answer.
I'm trying to explain you in details my procedure to make it easier to find my mistake

Comment: You cannot use two nodes for Vault with Raft because the cluster must reach quorum, and if each server votes for a different leader then the gossip protocol will be deadlocked and the cluster cannot initialize. That is also quite possibly the issue you are encountering.

Comment: I aslo don't realy understand this because If we have 3 server that we call A B C, if A votes B, B votes C and C votes A we have the same problem that you explained with even with an even number, Thus having 2 nodes shouldn't be a problem, I should be able to join my second node and then to join my third one. ( I don't know if it's clear sorry )

Comment: This may help explain: https://raft.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my problem came from the fact that I had the wrong configuration for my VM's and they couldn't communicate with each other (*face palm*). For those who wonder if my config files are good, just put private ip's instead of public ip's and everything should be good. :)